# Echo different table columns in every other row in table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm creating a questionnaire. The questions and their answers are stored in a table like so:
[image: questions table]

Now, I want to display the questions and their answers in a table where I get the questions and their possible answers on different rows. Like so:

[image: to be displayed like this]

In my php file, I echo the table and the rows but I cannot figure out how to put the questions and answer in different rows. here is how it looks like:
[image: My table]

and here is my php code:

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $status=$_GET["status"];
    include 'dbh.inc.php';
?>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table {
            width: 100%;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }
        table, td, th {

            text-align: left;
            padding: 8px;
        }
        #td_box{
            text-align: center;
        }
        tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2}
        th {
            background-color: #006689;
            color: white;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
        <body>
            <?php
            if ($status=="disp") {
                $sql="SELECT * FROM questions";
                $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
                echo "<table>";
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo $row["question"]; echo "</td>";
                    echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionA"];echo $row["optionB"];echo $row["optionC"];
                    echo $row["optionD"];echo $row["optionE"];echo "</td>"; 
                }
            }
            echo "</table>";
            ?>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1st :** Put all option radio buttons in another `tr` .

**2nd :** Maintain proper name attribute for radio button .`name="question[$row['question_id']]"`

**3rd :** And use `colspan="4"` for question `td`

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr >";
                echo "<td colspan='4'>"; echo $row["question"]; echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>"; 
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"question[$row['question_id']]\" value=\"$row['optionA']\" >".$row['optionA'];
               echo "</td>";
               echo "<td>";  
               echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"question[$row['question_id']]\" value=\"$row['optionB']\" >".$row['optionB'];
               echo "</td>"; 
               echo "<td>"; 
               echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"question[$row['question_id']]\" value=\"$row['optionC']\" >".$row['optionC'];
                echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>";  
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"question[$row['question_id']]\" value=\"$row['optionD']\" >".$row['optionD'];
                echo "</td>"; 
                echo "<td>"; 
                echo "<input type=\"radio\" name=\"question[$row['question_id']]\" value=\"$row['optionE']\" >".$row['optionE'];
                echo "</td>"; 
                echo "</tr>"; 
            }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. The radio buttons apear but not the texts (agree, disagree etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<?php
        if ($status=="disp") {
            $sql="SELECT * FROM questions";
            $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo "<table>";
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["question"]; echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionA"];echo $row["optionB"];echo $row["optionC"];
                echo $row["optionD"];echo $row["optionE"];echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>"; 
            }
        }
        echo "</table>";
        ?>
```

What I did:

I added a `</tr>` after your question echo and opend a new one directly after. Then I closed that `<tr>` after your last `<td>` as you forgot to do that.

Answer (score 0):

```
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td colspan='4'>"; echo $row["question"]; echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionA"];echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionB"];echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionC"];echo "</td>";
                echo "<td>"; echo $row["optionD"];echo "</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
```

this way you will have proper answers in tabular format in aligned manner